# Jenkins test connection not working with Ansible-Awx 7.0.0

Tags: jenkins-plugins, ansible-awx

Getting the following error testing the connection to the AWX node.

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST /jenkins/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible_tower.util.TowerInstallation/testTowerConnection.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

I'm also unable to do a curl manually from the jenkins servers. It times out. This is a docker awx install on RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an ACL issue. Was led to believe they were opened but don't believe they are.